# What is the difference between 1st and 2nd command?

Tags: apt, package-management, samba

What is the different when install `samba` using

```
sudo apt-get install samba
```

and using this command

```
sudo apt-get install samba samba-vfs-modules winbind bind9 bind9utils ldb-tools ntp smbldap-tools libnss-winbind libpam-winbind
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first command will install the package `samba` and all its dependencies.

The second command will install `samba` and bunch of other packages and also their dependencies.

The second command is useful when you are extending the functionality of `samba` and need extra packages to be present to do so.

---

Note that, most of these packages comes as recommended or suggested while installing `samba`:

```
$ apt-cache depends samba | grep -E 'Recommends|Suggests'
  Suggests: bind9
  Suggests: bind9utils
  Suggests: ldb-tools
  Suggests: ntp
  Suggests: smbldap-tools
  Suggests: winbind
  Suggests: ufw
  Recommends: attr
  Recommends: logrotate
  Recommends: samba-dsdb-modules
  Recommends: samba-vfs-modules
```

As the recommended packages are install by default, you can tell `apt-get` to install suggested packages:

```
sudo apt-get install --install-suggests samba
```

this will save you from typing long command line. Then you just need to install any packages explicitly from that list of yours, if missing.

Comment: thanks yous so much , u made me understand now. is this packages usefull to instal nas as that what iam trying to do ?

Comment: @Egytich Your way is fine as long as you are comfortable with it..